# Getting Error Flashing Android Things with Starter Kit

Tags: android-things

I recently picked up an Android Things Kit at Google Developer Days India. I was trying to setup it up via my Mac. I downloaded the Android Things Setup Utility from the Android things console. I tried to run it and it started installing the firmware. **It stopped saying "Exit Status 1"**. What am i doing wrong?

```
Android Things Setup Utility (version 1.0.16)
============================
This tool will help you install Android Things on your board and set up Wi-Fi.

What do you want to do?
1 - Install Android Things and optionally set up Wi-Fi
2 - Set up Wi-Fi on an existing Android Things device
1
What hardware are you using?
1 - Raspberry Pi 3
2 - NXP Pico i.MX7D
3 - NXP Pico i.MX6UL
2
You chose NXP Pico i.MX7D.


Looking for devices... This can take up to 3 minutes.
found device
Unzipping image...
Flashing Android Things. This will take a few minutes...
*Do not disconnect or interrupt!*

target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (559 KB)...
OKAY [  0.018s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.250s]
finished. total time: 0.268s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.000s
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'gpt' (33 KB)...
OKAY [  0.004s]
writing 'gpt'...
OKAY [  0.434s]
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.439s
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes

Error: error flashing android things: exit status 1
Stopping adb server...
Stopped adb server...
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, it is because MacOS does not provide `mke2fs`.

I found one in the unzipped image folder (`android-things-setup-utility/quickstart-temp/unzipped/mke2fs`).

And run `mv android-things-setup-utility/quickstart-temp/unzipped/mke2fs /usr/local/bin`

Hope this can help.